# Autocomplete Search Component for TextBoxes in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, jquery, vb.net

I'd like to use a component similar to the `Tags` autocomplete component used by Stack Overflow in my ASP.NET 2.0 application. What can I use?

Comment: This is not meta-material, voters. This is a real question, using a local example.

Comment: Temporarily closed and reopened to wipe of the "belongs on meta" votes and to prevent migration.  If you think this should be closed for some other reason that's fine, but as @Jonathan pointed out, it's definitely not for meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses [JQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete). If you want something *like* it, you can use the [Ajax Control toolkit's Autocomplete](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx).

You can't get there with just a serverside component alone; you'll have to use JavaScript or JQuery to make it work.